# Alternative to heavy website video background that could actually work great as .gif

Tags: flash, video, ogg

**Alternative to heavy website video background that could actually work great as .gif if not for the resolution and where it would work perfect as a flash animation only if flash was not defunct**

I would like to display a video background on my website. 
This is not an actual recorded video tape, it is made from a Macromedia Flash animated track.

That animation uses a fixed background. Just like a *.gif file would save a lot of physical memory re-using the same background on all the frames, I was hoping to find a similar trick for a different format:

- background is the same from start to finish
- the border has some simple 'light rotating around' effect
- the rest is just some images and texts fading-in, fading-out

I have tried converting it to *.gif, I ended up with a 98MB file.

- In *.mov 820*312, 25 fps it gives me a 8 Mo file.
- In *.mp4 820*312, 25 fps it gives me a 21 Mo file.
- In .swf, best quality ever, it gives me a tiny 325 Ko file...

It is 22 s long sequence.

Isn't there a better alternative to a *.mov *.ogg *.mp4 *WEBM video background out there when the video is actually an animation.

Answer (score 0):

The video codec will automatically detect a stationary background, encode it once, and reuse it for every frame. I suggest you encode the video with no additional key frames,(other than the first) and use a lower bitrate, under 1mbps, and use a very slow preset.

Or recreate the animations in canvas.